# usb wifi keeps dropping the connection

Tags: 16.04, networking, wireless, usb

I use the TP-Link TL-WN823N wifi adapter, which connects to Alcatel Link Zone MW40V wifi router. OS is Ubuntu Xenial.

My script checks the connection every 1 sec. by pinging my router.

Every few minutes the connection is dropped for 10 seconds. Sometimes it takes longer, until I reconnect my usb device.

Here is the result of the script suggested for this issue*:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/25666809/

And here is the syslog, around the time I loose the connection:

```
Oct  3 14:52:35 konrad kernel: [48057.888362] RTL871X: rtl8192e_sreset_xmit_status_check tx hang 
Oct  3 14:52:35 konrad kernel: [48058.003310] RTL871X: SetHwReg8192E(enxd46e0e147875): [HW_VAR_MACID_SLEEP] macid=0, org reg_0x4d4=0x00000000
Oct  3 14:52:37 konrad kernel: [48060.078834] RTL871X: survey done event(e) band:0 for enxd46e0e147875
Oct  3 14:52:37 konrad kernel: [48060.078851] RTL871X: rtw_indicate_scan_done(enxd46e0e147875)
Oct  3 14:52:43 konrad kernel: [48065.904390] RTL871X: rtl8192e_sreset_xmit_status_check tx hang 
Oct  3 14:52:45 konrad kernel: [48067.908373] RTL871X: rtl8192e_sreset_xmit_status_check tx hang 
Oct  3 14:52:47 konrad kernel: [48069.912351] RTL871X: rtl8192e_sreset_xmit_status_check tx hang 
Oct  3 14:52:49 konrad kernel: [48071.916318] RTL871X: rtl8192e_sreset_xmit_status_check tx hang 
Oct  3 14:52:51 konrad kernel: [48073.920294] RTL871X: rtl8192e_sreset_xmit_status_check tx hang 
Oct  3 14:52:53 konrad kernel: [48075.924656] RTL871X: rtl8192e_sreset_xmit_status_check tx hang 
Oct  3 14:52:55 konrad kernel: [48077.928901] RTL871X: rtl8192e_sreset_xmit_status_check tx hang 
Oct  3 14:52:59 konrad kernel: [48081.936320] RTL871X: rtl8192e_sreset_xmit_status_check tx hang 
Oct  3 14:53:01 konrad kernel: [48083.940556] RTL871X: rtl8192e_sreset_xmit_status_check tx hang 
Oct  3 14:53:03 konrad kernel: [48085.944913] RTL871X: rtl8192e_sreset_xmit_status_check tx hang 
Oct  3 14:53:05 konrad kernel: [48087.948873] RTL871X: rtl8192e_sreset_xmit_status_check tx hang 
Oct  3 14:53:07 konrad kernel: [48089.952599] RTL871X: rtl8192e_sreset_xmit_status_check tx hang 
Oct  3 14:53:09 konrad kernel: [48091.956913] RTL871X: rtl8192e_sreset_xmit_status_check tx hang 
Oct  3 14:53:11 konrad kernel: [48093.960434] RTL871X: rtl8192e_sreset_xmit_status_check tx hang
```

What I did:

1. I disabled power saving with

   options 8192eu rtw_power_mgnt=0 rtw_enusbss=1 rtw_ips_mode=1

In /etc/modprobe.d/8192eu.conf

2. I disabled support for IPv6, did not work, so I enabled it again
3. I upgraded network-manager with:

   sudo apt-get install network-manager
4. To dismiss the theory that it's a router which disables the connection when inactive, I wrote a script pinging it every 1 sec, plus, this script tells me exactly when the connection drops, so I hoped seeing a related (in time) message in /var/log/syslog which doesn't really helped, because the connection is dropped usually in the middle of:

> konrad kernel: [  515.730095] RTL871X:
>   rtw_indicate_scan_done(enxd46e0e147875)

Sometimes, but not always, it is preceded by:

> konrad kernel: [  515.730060] RTL871X: survey done event(f) band:0
>   for enxd46e0e147875

BTW, the icon of wifi in the taskbar says it is still "connected". Which isn't true.

Please... I've been struggling with it for weeks now...

---

*this is the script which generated the above report:
[My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425205#425205)

Comment: Use WPA2-AES only.

Comment: @MichaelBay - thanks, but no. I've just changed settings on my router to do that - WPA2 and AES (was WPA2 and Auto before) - no changes.

Comment: could you solve this issue? I have the same problem.